# Not Working : Highcharts bar plotOptions series className

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to apply style to the bar
But this code does not working
Please help!

plotOptions.series.className <<=== not working

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.className

//css

```
._chart_bar {
border-radius: 3px;
width: 8px;
```

}

//js

```
   Highcharts.chart(containerId, {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingLeft: 20,
    spacingRight: 20,
    height: 150,
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories,
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: xAxisFormatter,
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  exporting: {
    // 상단 우측 context 메뉴 없애기
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'percent',
      className: '_chart_bar',  <=============== here is not working
      color: barColor,
    },
  },
  series: seriesValues,
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}, () => {});
```

}, [categories, seriesValues, barColor]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `className` property works correctly - you can see that your CSS class is added to a series group element correctly.

To style the columns, you need to use `.highcharts-point` CSS class or the custom one, added by `className` property for points.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4xz2rwfp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.className